# html без переписывания кода

Tags: html

Можно-ли сделать так чтобы в моем index.html подгружался кусок кода из специального файла, например _header.html, как это сделано, например, в sass? Допустим я делаю сайт с большим количеством страничек и постоянно меняю шапку сайта и мне приходиться тратить много времени на копипастинг, вот я и задался таким вопросом. Можно ли сделать, как-бы, функцию в html. Может то как я изложил решение, которое могло бы быть в корне не верно, но суть вопроса думаю понятна

Comment: Решение зависит от того, на каком языке программирования написан сайт. Например в `php` и других можно просто использовать `include` или `require`, или использовать `jquery` для подгрузки частей html через `$('IDПоляКудаЗагрузить').load('ФайлHtml')` и так же другие варианты.

Comment: Обычно для этого используют шаблонизатор на сервере или собирают готовые странички с помощью статических генераторов сайтов. Если же нужно на чистом html без дополнительных приблуд, то придётся делать фрейм или подгружать через ajax, так как в html подобная штука не встроена

Comment: Понял, я знал что можно сделать это через пхп, но думал что может такая штучка в html встроена. Жаль)

Comment: [импорт html](https://habr.com/ru/post/230751/)

Comment: @Denis640Kb в файле .html не будет работать php. Если, конечно, сервер не извращенцы настраивали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если html сделать php файлом и туда можно вставить код, который в зависимости от условия (например параметров в строке запроса) берет разные шапки. примерно так:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
Test page
</head>
<?php
if ($_GET['header']=1) {
    require_once('/path/to-header1.inc.html');
} else {
    require_once('/path/to-hedaer2.inc.html');
}
?>
<body>

some text

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно на html при помощи тега `<iframe>`
В зависимости от адреса страницы ( window.location.href) можно ставить ему разные src='путь к шапке.html'